# How to get last value from line chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to display the latest temperature readings from a line chart that I have generated based on this [template](https://github.com/HandsOnDataViz/chartjs-templates/tree/master/line-chart).

I was thinking to just put the numbers in an HTML tag like this.

```
$().ready(function() {
  $("#Temperature 1").html('GET LAST READINGS FROM DATA HERE');
});
```

I guess the question is how do I access the last element in the data that has been parsed with Papa parse?

Apologies in advance (no javascript knowledge), I usually can find examples here but this time I've not been able to find anything similar to what I want.

Comment: This isn't specifically related to your question, but tag names can't have spaces. `#Temperature 1` should be something like `#temperature-1`.

Comment: Why not just use the data directly instead of trying to extract if from the chart?

Comment: Hi Matt, Yes - will I have to read it again?  Or can I access it from the `datasets` variable?  `datasets` appears to be some sort of a list of lists, can it be addressed something like `datasets[0][-1]` ?

Comment: Understood about the HTML tag.

Comment: You won't have to read it again. Access the data from the variable. Note that array indices can't be negative, so you'll have to use something like `datasets[0][datasets[0].length - 1]`.

Comment: @MattF. Thanks for the help - I figured it out - I needed to use the `data` property of datasets.  It can be accessed like this `datasets[0].data[4]`, and now the HTML tag works.  Now I have to figure out how to access the last not null value :-)

Comment: You're using css: you can use the last-child modifier on the parent.